# How do I delete a row from a UITableView programmatically and update the UI

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift3, xcode8

**UPDATE:**

I have discovered the reason it took up to 10 seconds before updating the `UITableView`. It has something to do with the HTTP POST request which I'm sending to my server. Below is my code as of now after reading all the answers and searching online. The reason is for the placement of the variables `index`, `indexPath` and the call to `self.tableView(tableView: UITableView UITableView, commit: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAt: IndexPath)`.

If I move them outside of the `task` closure they execute immediately, but I do not want them outside since I need the "OK" from the server before deleting.

The problem is not with the server response time as I get the response instantly. I think it has something to do with `task.resume()` which I'm not really familiar with.

```
foreach expense in expenses {
    var request = URLRequest(url: URL(string: Constants.ZEBON_SERVER_URL)!)
    request.httpMethod = "POST"
    let postString = "date=\(expense.date)&amount=\(expense.amount)&note=\(expense.desc)"
    request.httpBody = postString.data(using: .utf8)
    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) {
        (data: Data?, response: URLResponse?, error: Error?) in

        if error != nil {
            print("error = \(error)")
        }

        // If the server responds with "OK" (the request was received) then delete the expense
        if responseString?.range(of:"return\":\"ok") != nil {
            let index = self.expenses.index(of: expense)
            let indexPath = IndexPath(row: index!, section: 0)

            // Deletes the expense
            self.tableView(self.tableView, commit: .delete, forRowAt: indexPath)
        }
        else {
            // TODO: Implement error handling.
        }
   }
   task.resume()
}
```

**ORIGINAL QUESTION:**

I have some objects that are displayed in a `UITableView`. When I press a button, they are sent to a server and should be removed from the tableView.

My current code looks like this:

```
let index = self.expenses.index(of: expense)
let indexPath = NSIndexPath(row: index!, section: 0)
self.expenses.remove(at: indexPath.row)

// Saves the array 'Expenses' to persistent storage.
self.saveExpenses()

self.tableView.beginUpdates()
self.tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath as IndexPath], with: .none)
self.tableView.endUpdates()
```

My problem is that the expense is sent to the server and removed from storage, but the `UITableView` does not refresh, so the cell stays visible while I cannot interact with it in any way.

Comment: Are you doing this on main thread?

Comment: Even after using tableview.ReloadData()?

Comment: You need to add `self.tableView.reloadData()` into your code

Comment: @Maddyヅヅ No, do not call `reloadData`.

Comment: Where is the code you posted in your question? Provide some context. And make sure all UI updates are on the main thread.

Answer (score 1):

Save the array **after** updating the UI.

Actually theses lines are sufficient, `begin/endUpdates()` has no effect for a single delete operation.

```
let index = self.expenses.index(of: expense)
let indexPath = IndexPath(row: index!, section: 0)
self.expenses.remove(at: index!)
DispatchQueue.main.async {
    self.tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .none)
}

// Saves the array 'Expenses' to persistent storage.
self.saveExpenses()
```

Comment: I tried moving it after, but just like with Lion's answer above it is extremely slow (about 5 seconds before the cell updates)

Comment: Reloading the entire table view is more expensive than calling the delete method. Try to update the table view on the main thread. I updated the answer.

Comment: How does moving the call to `saveExpenses` make any difference?

Comment: @rmaddy  From SO experience I know that many coders got an affinity for synchronous tasks ;-)

Comment: I have no idea how your last comment answers my question. Again, how does moving `self.saveExpenses()` change anything? The only relevant change (possibly, until we hear more from the OP), is ensuring the call to `deleteRows` is on the main queue.

Comment: @rmaddy The OP wrote *...that the expense is sent to the server*. If that's a **synchronous** task, it will take some time and block the thread and that makes a difference.

Comment: True. I got focused on the OP's statement that the table view is never refreshed at all. Their posted code may result in a delay, but they claim it is never updated.